# jQuery: Get reference to parent after the element is replaced

Tags: jquery, onclick, parent

**Case:**

I am working on a new jQuery photo gallery. Currently I am merging three different libraries and writing some of custom code to scale up the functionality of the gallery. But I am stuck at this piece of script for past 2 hours and couldn't think of a way through.

There is piece of script in one of the libraries that appends some markup to `body`. This is the markup that is added.

```
<div class='custom' data-oid=1>
    <div class='page-link' data-attr=1>Page Link</div>
    <div class='page-link' data-attr=2>Page Link</div>
</div>
<div class='custom' data-oid=2>
    <div class='page-link' data-attr=1>Page Link</div>
    <div class='page-link' data-attr=2>Page Link</div>
</div>
```

I want to listen to `click` events of class `page-link` to perform some changes in other libraries. As the markup added is dynamic I use the following script to catch the `click` event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.page-link', function () {
    //Print value of parent data attribute
    alert($(this).parent().attr('data-oid'));
});
```

**Issue:**

It should work right. But the issue is that the library that added the markup is also listening to the `click` events. And once I click on `page-link` the library replaces the clicked element with another element. Due to this the clicked element is lost along with its scope and `.parent()` in my code is not able to get the parent.

So my question is: Is there a way to get the value of parent's attr `data-oid` even after the scope is lost?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQLKL/)**

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As the event bubbles, you can attach the click handler to the parent, and do your own check for wether or not the target is `.page-link`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.custom', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('page-link')) {
        $(e.target).replaceWith('<h2>Link Modified</h2>');
        alert( $(this).attr('data-oid') );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MQLKL/2/)